# Strange insect identification

Tags: zoology

Tonight I have found this new friend flyng inside my home. First time ever I sea something like this here in the north East of Italy   [image: photo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an Oleander Hawk Moth, *Daphnis nerii*. Order Lepidoptera,family Sphigidae. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daphnis_nerii